# Automating proxy configuration across multiple applications without plaintext password

Tags: environment-variables, encryption, proxy, windows-subsystem-for-linux, rc

More generally than the post described here: [Using bash functionality in rc files](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/752484/using-bash-functionality-in-rc-files?noredirect=1#comment1432155_752484)

I would like to set an appropriate proxy configuration for all/multiple applications including but not limited to: snap/apt/cpan/pip/wget/curl. Moreover, I would like to avoid having my proxy password displayed anywhere in plaintext. How/is it possible to achieve this?

[This post](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/279670/how-can-i-specify-a-system-wide-proxy-without-giving-my-password-in-plaintext) implies that every system process will be configured for proxy via `/etc/environment`. I have not had such success (see EDIT), so I am currently under the assumption that all proxy configurations must be made per application. Regarding the [linked post](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/266808/avoiding-plain-text-password-in-http-proxy/266934#266934), and the use of `secret-tool`, it seems to me that this assumes the file defining the proxy configuration(s) can evaluate bash expressions (which hasn't been my experience with the `.curlrc`/`.wgetrc` files).

EDIT:

With the contents of `etc/environment` equal to:

```
http_proxy=http://user:pass@proxy.com:80
https_proxy=http://user:pass@proxy.com:80
```

and the contents of my `.curlrc` file equal to:

```
proxy=http://user:pass@proxy.com:80
```

I can run:

```
curl https://unix.stackexchange.com/posts/752654/edit --output test.html
  % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                                 Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
100 70115    0 70115    0     0    99k      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:--   99k
```

which generates `test.html` as expected.

Without changing the contents of `/etc/environment` and removing the `.curlrc` file, the download hangs indefinitely:

```
curl https://unix.stackexchange.com/posts/752654/edit --output test.html
  % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                                 Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
  0     0    0     0    0     0      0      0 --:--:--  0:00:25 --:--:--     0
```

I'm using RHEL on WSL.

Comment: "I am currently under the assumption that all proxy configurations must be made per application." While every process *can* decide for itself, proxy configuration is pretty consistent these days, through the means you mention. So, please describe what actually goes wrong. Let's fix the actual problems you have, not hypothetical ones.

Comment: @MarcusMüller Made an edit - hope that clarifies

Comment: it doesn't. What does not work?

Comment: @MarcusMüller Maybe I should start with: is there a *system-wide* proxy configuration that will work for all applications? Follow-up question: am I correct in understanding that the system-wide configuration resides in `/etc/environment`? If yes, why do the parameters (in `/etc/environment` above not work [in the absence of .curlrc/.wgetrc having the same parameters]) to e.g. successfully download a file with wget or curl?

Comment: yes, the one you mentioned. **What does not work**? Please give a concrete example.

Comment: @MarcusMüller Provided in post edit

Comment: Thanks! But the thing here is, when it does *not* work, you had removed the edit in the /etc/environment. OK, that's expected. But if it's in /etc/environment (and *not* in curlrc), it's working, right?

Comment: @MarcusMüller No ("Without changing the contents of /etc/environment..."). In both scenarios, the proxy configuration is set in `/etc/environment`. Only when the proxy config is set in `.curlrc` can I successfully curl.

Comment: That's the interesting part! With the environment variables still set (I assume they are, check with `echo Proxy for HTTP: $http_proxy, for HTTPS: $https_proxy`), run a `curl -vv https://unix.stackexchange.com/posts/752654/edit`. The first line should be `* Uses proxy env variable https_proxy`. Is it?

Comment: @MarcusMüller The variables are unset: "Proxy for HTTP: , for HTTPS: ". First line in curl execution is `Trying 151.101.193.69:443...`

Comment: ah, so that means that your changes /etc/environment never had effect. You did reboot after you put your `http_proxy=..` and `https_proxy=...` in there?

Comment: @MarcusMüller Just to be sure, I rebooted again. The variables still are not set

Comment: Since the current issue appears to be `/etc/environment` not behaving as expected, how are you logging into the machine to run `curl`?  I believe `/etc/environment` is processed with PAM through `pam_env.so`.  Also, what operating system are you attempting this on?

Comment: This is a WSL RHEL instance

Comment: ah that's the critical piece of info that was missing!

Comment: So here's the deal: I don't have a windows machine, so I can't test it. However, multiple sources say that /etc/profile isn't sourced by bash launched in WSL, so that's probably the underlying issue. Can you try to open a WSL shell, run `export https_proxy=yourproxy...`, then `curl -vv https://unix.stackexchange.com/posts/752654/edit` from the same? If that works, we just need to figure out how to permanently set environment variables in WSL. My guess is, you can set an environment variable in your host Windows to set environment variables inside.

Comment: yup that works! can I not just export the variables in my `.bashrc` (which is sourced on launch in WSL [and what implications would this have])?

Comment: got it i think `wsl -d RedHat -u root -- /bin/login -f <user>`. So just to clarify, this environment variable should work for all of snap/apt/cpan/pip/wget/curl, etc?

Comment: they usually do :) I mean, I really can't look into every program and guarantee it (it's really the choice every program that does a HTTP request makes), but in my experience that works. (Snap might be a bit special; I think it reads /etc/environment on its own? Can't remember.)